# A global axis with one x-axis-lable, y-axis-lable and legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams

I am in need of your help.
I have a problem with which I am struggling for a few days, but can not find a solution to it.

I would like to place three charts side by side.

All charts should have the same x-axis-lable, y-axis-lable and legend. I.e. not each chart individually, but a global axis-lable so to speak.

**Edit:**

-All three y-axes are scaled the same and only need a global legend(and values).

-The x-axis values should remain, but the label (R) should be global.

-There can be multiple plots in each diagram, so it is nicer if the legend is flush over the three diagrams.

**Edit2:**

There is one small blemish. Is it possible to bring the legend (lots of text) exactly flush with the charts on the left and right? (See my example code!)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm,height=6cm}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
    \begin{axis}[name=leftplot, width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,
                    grid=major,                 
                    cycle list name=color,
                    ylabel={R},
%                   xlabel={x},
                    ylabel near ticks,
                    ]               
        \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[name=middleplot, at ={($(leftplot.east)+(1cm,0)$)}, anchor=west,
                    width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,
                    grid=major,                 
                    cycle list name=color,
%                   ylabel={R},
                    xlabel={x},
                    ylabel near ticks,
                    legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south, 
                        legend columns=3, column sep=6pt}
                    ]               
        \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
        \addlegendentry{11 1111 111 }
        \addlegendentry{22 2222 222};
        \addlegendentry{33 3333 333};
        \addlegendentry{44 4444 444};
        \addlegendentry{55 5555 555};
        \addlegendentry{66 6666 666};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[name=rightplot, at = {($(middleplot.east)+(1cm,0)$)}, anchor=west,
                    width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,
                    grid=major,                 
                    cycle list name=color,
%                   ylabel={R},
%                   xlabel={x},
                    ylabel near ticks,
                    legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south, 
                        legend columns=3, column sep=6pt}
                    ]               
        \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\caption{Example}
\end{figure}
        
\end{document}
```

Many greetings
Parsec

1: Picture: Final (It should look like this)
[image]

2: Code-Example

```
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \pgfplotsset{width=6cm,height=6cm}
        \begin{document}
        \begin{figure}
        \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
        \begin{axis}[width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,
                                    grid=major,                 
                                    cycle list name=color,
                                    ylabel={R},
                                    xlabel={x},
                                    ylabel near ticks,
                                    ]               
                                    \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}   
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
        \begin{axis}[width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,
                                    grid=major,                 
                                    cycle list name=color,
                                    ylabel={R},
                                    xlabel={x},
                                    ylabel near ticks,
                                    legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)},anchor=south, legend columns=3,column sep=6pt}
]               
                                    \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                                \addlegendentry{1}
                                \addlegendentry{2};
                                \addlegendentry{3};
                                \addlegendentry{4};
                                \addlegendentry{5};
                                \addlegendentry{6};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}                           
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
        \begin{axis}[width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,
                                    grid=major,                 
                                    cycle list name=color,
                                    ylabel={R},
                                    xlabel={x},
                                    ylabel near ticks,
                                    ]                                       
                                    \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};                            
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}
        \end{center}
        \caption{Example}
        \end{figure}
        
        \end{document}
```

Comment: Just an  idea. Don't label x axis on first and third plot, don't label y axis on second and third plot. Add external legend on third plot.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I just tried this but run into a problem with the legend. Since I have multiple plots per chart I have to put them over the three images (after all). That would not succeed with your idea, since then the first and last diagram is shifted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a first test with OP's code. Every plot is an independent `tikzpicture` and  they are aligned according their `baseline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm,height=6cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
    \begin{axis}[width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,
                    grid=major,                 
                    cycle list name=color,
                    ylabel={R},
%                   xlabel={x},
                    ylabel near ticks,
                    ]               
        \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
    \begin{axis}[width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,
                    grid=major,                 
                    cycle list name=color,
%                   ylabel={R},
                    xlabel={x},
                    ylabel near ticks,
                    legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south, 
                        legend columns=3, column sep=6pt}
                    ]               
        \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
        \addlegendentry{1}
        \addlegendentry{2};
        \addlegendentry{3};
        \addlegendentry{4};
        \addlegendentry{5};
        \addlegendentry{6};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
    \begin{axis}[width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,
                    grid=major,                 
                    cycle list name=color,
%                   ylabel={R},
%                   xlabel={x},
                    ylabel near ticks,
                    legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south, 
                        legend columns=3, column sep=6pt}
                    ]               
        \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\caption{Example}
\end{figure}
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Second option: All plots are inte the same `tikzpicture` and they are aligned according their "node" anchors fixed with a `name` option for every plot. This solution is shown in `groupplots` library section.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm,height=6cm}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
    \begin{axis}[name=leftplot, width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,
                    grid=major,                 
                    cycle list name=color,
                    ylabel={R},
%                   xlabel={x},
                    ylabel near ticks,
                    ]               
        \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[name=middleplot, at ={($(leftplot.east)+(1cm,0)$)}, anchor=west,
                    width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,
                    grid=major,                 
                    cycle list name=color,
%                   ylabel={R},
                    xlabel={x},
                    ylabel near ticks,
                    legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south, 
                        legend columns=3, column sep=6pt}
                    ]               
        \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
        \addlegendentry{1}
        \addlegendentry{2};
        \addlegendentry{3};
        \addlegendentry{4};
        \addlegendentry{5};
        \addlegendentry{6};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[name=rightplot, at = {($(middleplot.east)+(1cm,0)$)}, anchor=west,
                    width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,
                    grid=major,                 
                    cycle list name=color,
%                   ylabel={R},
%                   xlabel={x},
                    ylabel near ticks,
                    legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south, 
                        legend columns=3, column sep=6pt}
                    ]               
        \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\caption{Example}
\end{figure}
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Third option: Using `groupplots` library

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{width=6cm,height=6cm}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
\begin{groupplot}[%
    group style={%
        group size=3 by 1,
    },
    width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,
    grid=major, cycle list name=color, ylabel near ticks,
    legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south, legend columns=3, column sep=6pt}
    ] 
    \nextgroupplot[ylabel={R}]           
        \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
    \nextgroupplot[xlabel={x}]            
        \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
        \addlegendentry{1};
        \addlegendentry{2};
        \addlegendentry{3};
        \addlegendentry{4};
        \addlegendentry{5};
        \addlegendentry{6};
    \nextgroupplot            
        \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
\end{groupplot} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: Aligning with legend margins

To align first and third plot with the long legend borders, the easiest way is to draw the central plot first and use `outer` anchors (the legend defines them) to fix lateral plots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm,height=6cm}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
    \begin{axis}[name=middleplot, 
                    width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,
                    grid=major,                 
                    cycle list name=color,
%                   ylabel={R},
                    xlabel={x},
                    ylabel near ticks,
                    legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south, 
                        legend columns=3, column sep=6pt}
                    ]               
        \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
        \addlegendentry{11 1111 111 }
        \addlegendentry{22 2222 222};
        \addlegendentry{33 3333 333};
        \addlegendentry{44 4444 444};
        \addlegendentry{55 5555 555};
        \addlegendentry{66 6666 666};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[name=leftplot, at ={(middleplot.outer west|-middleplot.center)}, anchor=west,
                         width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,
                    grid=major,                 
                    cycle list name=color,
                    ylabel={R},
%                   xlabel={x},
                    ylabel near ticks,
                    ]               
        \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[name=rightplot, at = {(middleplot.center-|middleplot.outer east)}, anchor=east,
                    width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,
                    grid=major,                 
                    cycle list name=color,
%                   ylabel={R},
%                   xlabel={x},
                    ylabel near ticks,
                    legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south, 
                        legend columns=3, column sep=6pt}
                    ]               
        \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
                \addplot coordinates {(1,6.45)(2,3.4)(3,4.8)(4,4.1)(5,4.4)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\caption{Example}
\end{figure}
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello,
thank you very much for your detailed answer.
The second code seems to be very close to the solution for my problem. Thank you very much for that. There is one small blemish. Is it possible to bring the legend (lots of text) exactly flush with the charts on the left and right? (See my example code!)
Many greetings
Parsec

Comment: Hello,
thank you very much for your detailed answer.
The second code seems to be very close to the solution for my problem. Thank you very much for that. There is one small blemish. Is it possible to bring the legend (lots of text) exactly flush with the charts on the left and right? (See my example code!: EDIT2).
Many greetings
Parsec

Comment: @Parsec Take a look at updated answer. I think I did what you wanted